# Oracle XML Query with multiple child nodes

Tags: xml, oracle

I would like to achieve a query on XML Element but could not find a proper way to achieve this.

Let's consider this table:

```
CREATE TABLE SUBSCRIPTIONS(
SUBSCRIPTION_ID NUMBER,
PARAMETERS_XML  CLOB
);
```

My XML looks like:

```
<Model>
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter>
      <userParameter>outlets</userParameter>
       <Values>
         <Value>45</Value>
         <Value>676</Value>
         <Value>1502</Value>
         ...
       </Values>
    </Parameter>
  </Parameters>
</Model>
```

I'm trying for each subscription to get from the XML, the parameter name, and the parameters values, using this query:

```
SELECT
s.SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
s.PARAMETERS_XML,
xt.*
FROM EFNTA.SUBSCRIPTIONS s,
XMLTABLE(
    '/Model/Parameters/Parameter'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(s.PARAMETERS_XML)
    COLUMNS USER_PARAM  VARCHAR2(100)  PATH 'userParameter',
    PARAM_VALUE VARCHAR2(1000) PATH '//*:Values',
    CHECKED_LIST_EXCLUDE VARCHAR2(100) PATH '//*:CheckedListExclude'                        
) xt ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Issue is that when there are multiple values, the result is returned as one big concatenated chain:

[image]

Is there any easy way to separate theses values with a comma, semicolon, or whatever ? (I don't know the number of values in advance) I couln't find how to achieve this with XPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `string-join` function: `'string-join(Values//Value, ", ")'`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use FLOWR to rewrite the XML to to incude a trailing `,` in each `Value` element:

```sql
SELECT s.SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
       s.PARAMETERS_XML,
       xt.User_Param,
       RTRIM(xt.Param_Value, ',') AS Param_Value,
       xt.Checked_List_Exclude
FROM   EFNTA.SUBSCRIPTIONS s
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         'copy $e := .
         modify (
           for $i in $e/Model/Parameters/Parameter/Values/Value
           return replace node $i with <Value>{$i},</Value>
         )
         return $e/Model/Parameters/Parameter'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(s.PARAMETERS_XML)
         COLUMNS
           USER_PARAM  VARCHAR2(100)  PATH 'userParameter',
           PARAM_VALUE VARCHAR2(1000) PATH '//*:Values',
           CHECKED_LIST_EXCLUDE VARCHAR2(100) PATH '//*:CheckedListExclude'
        ) xt
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Or, as suggested by [Pavel Koryakin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71951599/1509264), use `string-join()`:

```sql
SELECT s.SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
       s.PARAMETERS_XML,
       xt.*
FROM   EFNTA.SUBSCRIPTIONS s
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '/Model/Parameters/Parameter'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(s.PARAMETERS_XML)
         COLUMNS
           USER_PARAM  VARCHAR2(100)  PATH 'userParameter',
           PARAM_VALUE VARCHAR2(1000) PATH 'Values/string-join(./Value/text(), ",")',
           CHECKED_LIST_EXCLUDE VARCHAR2(100) PATH '//CheckedListExclude'
        ) xt
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Which both output:

| SUBSCRIPTION_ID | PARAMETERS_XML | USER_PARAM | PARAM_VALUE | CHECKED_LIST_EXCLUDE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | <Model <Parameters> <Parameter> <userParameter>outlets</userParameter> <Values> <Value>45</Value> <Value>676</Value> <Value>1502</Value> </Values> </Parameter> </Parameters> </Model> | outlets | 45,676,1502 | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=00170bef1ac3c883653c4025e9fed515)*

Comment: Not sure how oracle will handle it, but I've tried in oxygen and there `string-join` doesn't put a trailing comma.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/ made my day, thank you!

Comment: @PavelKoryakin You are correct, there is no trailing comma to trim. I'd somehow managed to generate one using `string-join()` inside a FLOWR expression but I guess that was probably user error as it doesn't generate one in the XPATH.

Answer (score 2):

You could split the `Values` handling out to a second XMLTable:

```
SELECT
    s.SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
    xt1.USER_PARAM,
    xt2.PARAM_VALUE,
    xt1.CHECKED_LIST_EXCLUDE
FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS s
CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE(
    '/Model/Parameters/Parameter'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(s.PARAMETERS_XML)
    COLUMNS USER_PARAM  VARCHAR2(100)  PATH 'userParameter',
    PARAM_VALUES XMLTYPE PATH '//*:Values',
    CHECKED_LIST_EXCLUDE VARCHAR2(100) PATH '//*:CheckedListExclude'
) xt1
OUTER APPLY XMLTABLE(
    '/*:Values/Value'
    PASSING xt1.PARAM_VALUES
    COLUMNS PARAM_VALUE VARCHAR2(1000) PATH '.'
) xt2
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

| SUBSCRIPTION_ID | USER_PARAM | PARAM_VALUE | CHECKED_LIST_EXCLUDE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 553219 | outlets | 45 | *null* |
| 553219 | outlets | 1502 | *null* |
| 553219 | outlets | 676 | *null* |

And you can then aggregate the individual values:

```
SELECT
    s.SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
    xt1.USER_PARAM,
    LISTAGG(xt2.PARAM_VALUE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY xt2.PARAM_VALUE) as PARAM_VALUES,
    xt1.CHECKED_LIST_EXCLUDE
FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS s
CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE(
    '/Model/Parameters/Parameter'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(s.PARAMETERS_XML)
    COLUMNS USER_PARAM  VARCHAR2(100)  PATH 'userParameter',
    PARAM_VALUES XMLTYPE PATH '//*:Values',
    CHECKED_LIST_EXCLUDE VARCHAR2(100) PATH '//*:CheckedListExclude'
) xt1
OUTER APPLY XMLTABLE(
    '/*:Values/Value'
    PASSING xt1.PARAM_VALUES
    COLUMNS PARAM_VALUE VARCHAR2(1000) PATH '.'
) xt2
GROUP BY
    s.SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
    xt1.USER_PARAM,
    xt1.CHECKED_LIST_EXCLUDE
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

| SUBSCRIPTION_ID | USER_PARAM | PARAM_VALUES | CHECKED_LIST_EXCLUDE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 553219 | outlets | 1502,45,676 | *null* |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d8b61627c5419f72aa45a56a33bb71bb)

Your example has no namespaces so the wildcarding looks unnecessary (and I'd generally avoid wildcards anyway if possible), but I've left them in case you've simplified it.

I changed the first join to `cross apply` which means you'll still only see rows where `parameters_xml` is present, as in your original; but made the second `outer apply` so you will still see the parameter name even if there are no values.

I've also kind of ignored `CHECKED_LIST_EXCLUDE` as the example doesn't have that; if that can also have multiple values then you might need to do a similar thing for that.

Comment: This looks perfect, I only forgot to mention that I'm using Oracle 11g, and then, the APPLY syntax is not supported :-(

Comment: If you know there will always be a `Values` node then you can change both to `cross join`. Otherwise the FLOWR manipulation is probably going to be best. (And maybe/probably better anyway *8-)

Answer (score 1):

I finally handled it that way:

```
SELECT
s.SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
s.PARAMETERS_XML,
xt.USER_PARAM,
xt.CHECKED_LIST_EXCLUDE,
NVL(xt.PARAM_VALUE, xt.PARAM_VALUES) AS PARAM_VALUES
FROM EFNTA.SUBSCRIPTIONS s,
XMLTABLE(
    '/Model/Parameters/Parameter'
     PASSING XMLTYPE(s.PARAMETERS_XML)
     COLUMNS USER_PARAM  VARCHAR2(100)  PATH 'userParameter',
             CHECKED_LIST_EXCLUDE VARCHAR2(100) PATH '//*:CheckedListExclude',
             PARAM_VALUE VARCHAR2(4000) PATH 'Value',
             PARAM_VALUES VARCHAR2(4000) PATH 'string-join(Values//Value,";")'
 ) xt ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

I had to put another column, and a NVL, cause I noticed that sometimes I had a  node directly under the  node, and had the desired output:

[image]

Thanks for your suggestions, I'll keep all this under my sleeve, in case of :-)